# How can I run a transition or animation on top of a timeout in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, transition, css-animations

I am trying to create a navbar of sorts for my blog; I essentially want the blog description to roll and reveal interpage navigation on hover, which I have accomplished using some basic Javascript with the help of [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). The code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/CheeseTurtle/pen/JnfxL) on Codepen. [I'm kind of new to Javascript (and jQuery) and web dev in general, so forgive my terrible coding.]

Right now the background goes to blue during its forward rotation (the background color change will later be an inset box-shadow), but the going back to white part is the issue. **I would like for the box faces to slowly start going to back to white *while* the timeout is counting down (terminology?) and be set to complete the transition after the backward rotation is over; meaning, the back-to-white transition duration would be equal to the timeout length + the length of the rotate-backward transition.** (Since the timeout could be cleared/the forward rotation "canceled" before the back-to-white transition and/or the timeout period ends, the box faces may not return to being fully white before the to-blue transition is triggered again on mouseover.)

I don't exactly understand how .queue() and .dequeue() work; I think I'm trying to emulate multithreading with this though, so using those might not be what I'm looking for anyway.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is hard to read and understand as it is